# Spring Security - DefaultSecurityFilterChain empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring (non Boot) application with rest endpoints. Now I want to add security to request authentification for theese endpoints.

Note: This app is deployed on an jboss server.

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Inside the context.xml I scan for all spring component.

SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       httpSecurity
           .csrf().disable()
           .authorizeRequests()
             .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
           .and().httpBasic();

   }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        return new SimpleAuthenticationProvider();
    }
}
```

When I deploy the application there is following Message in the logs:

> [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] Will not secure any request

As a result the endpoints are not secured, I don't have to enter my credentials. Why is the List of filters empty? As I am not using Spring Boot (using an starter) what do I have to do to use Standard configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

I forgot to add the Filterproxy:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is the punishment for not using spring boot

Answer (score 0):

And for anyone configuring via code, here is the Kotlin version. I also suffered through this punishment. I assumed the @EnableWebSecurity annotation would register the filter but alas, it was not to be.

```
log.info("Adding Spring Security filter to servlet context")
val springSecurityFilterChain = DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain", dispatcherContext)
springSecurityFilterChain.setTargetFilterLifecycle(true)
val springSecurityRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", springSecurityFilterChain)
springSecurityRegistration.setAsyncSupported(true)
springSecurityRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(
    EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST,
               DispatcherType.ERROR,
               DispatcherType.ASYNC),
    false,
    "/*")
```